# Probability of reading a specific word?

Tags: probability, self-study, information-theory

Here's a problem I made up while reading David MacKay's *Information Theory, Learning Algorithms, and Inference*.

Suppose I have a vocabulary made up of two words, "foo", "barbaz" and I have a string that I've generated by writing "foo" with probability $ 2/3 $ and "barbaz" with probability $ 1/3 $. E.g., the string might look like "foobarbazbarbaz".

Say I'm reading a string generated in this way and I want to estimate the probability that the word I'm reading is "foo" without knowing anything about the current character I'm looking at (assuming that there are no spaces and I read characters at a constant rate). Obviously, if the two words in my vocabulary were of equal length, the probability would just be the probability with which I wrote "foo" when generating my string. However, since "barbaz" is 2x as long as "foo", there's intuitively a less than $ 2/3 $ probability that the current word I'm reading is foo.

I'm fairly certain the answer to this question is that the probability I'm currently reading a character from "foo" is
$$
\frac{(2/3)(3)}{(2/3)(3) + (1/3)(6)} = 1/2.
$$
but I'm finding this surprisingly hard to formalize.

The best way I can come up with to convince myself of this is to notice that this is just the probability weighted length of "foo" divided by the expected length of a word in my vocabulary but I feel like there must be a better way that actually introduces a random variable or event into the mix.

ETA: Clarification, assume I'm reading words from an infinite stream generated in this way.

Comment: It may be difficult to formalize because there is a special relation between the two words: neither is a substring of the other.  You already have the necessary random process.  As always, it can be described with a random variable by assigning distinct numbers (such as $0$ and $1$) to the two possible observations.

Comment: The contents of the words are _intentionally_ distinct characters. Is your point that you can just describe this as "doing Bayes"? If so, how? Part of my point is that I said you don't know what character you're reading, so the main difficulty that perhaps I didn't do a good job of highlighting is accounting for the words' different lengths. Clearly, if you observe an "o" you know you're in "foo". Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: I don't think I wrote or even intimated "Bayes." You have a well-defined sampling procedure that readily determines the chance of selecting any given copy of the word in the string.  Since you're aware of the overlap issue, the rest is much simpler than you are suggesting.

Comment: Apologies for falsely reading "Bayes" into your comment. Let me try and expand upon what you're saying to see if I understand. Above, I've defined a clear sampling procedure for characters, pick one of two words with the defined probabilities, and then insert the chosen word's characters into the stream. Now, per your original message we can let $ X $ be a binary random variable that takes value $ 0 $ if the observed character comes from "foo" and $ 1 $ if the observed character comes from "barbaz". 

Our goal is to estimate $ P(X = 0) $. Is this a valid expansion of your point?

Comment: Almost, but not quite: this does not appear to be an estimation problem, despite how it has been framed.  You are told everything you need to know about the data-generating and sampling procedures.  All you have to do is figure what the probabilities of $0$ and $1$ must be.  For it to be an estimation problem, you would also have to be told something about the data you have collected and how you sampled them--but I see nothing explicitly stated about that.

Comment: Right, I'm getting a little confused though. Bringing this back to the original question, my confusion is I'm not sure how to formalize accounting for the lengths as part of the sampling procedure. That is, what is the probability of being in one of the two words given that I'm reading characters from the stream sequentially? I appreciate you helping clarify what it is I'm asking but I still don't feel like I know how to answer the question.

Comment: Specifically, I am still confused about how to include the relative lengths as part of the probability calculation. One idea I have is that this is identical to having two equal length words with probabilities equal to $$ p * \text{length of "foo"} $$ and $$ (1-p) * \text{length of "barbaz"} $$.

Comment: When you are reading a string, it sounds like you are reading it sequentially.  Can we take that to imply you know what position your character is at?  If so, *the answer depends on the position.*

Comment: Should've been clearer, I was imagining an infinite stream so position doesn't matter.

Comment: In that case, what fraction of all the letters will be in the first word?  That will be the probability.